# How to get auth()->user() in api controller Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to get the logged in user id and insert it into the Salesprice table,I have tried the below code but it gives me the this error

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'setby_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `salesprices` (`book_id`,
>   `salesprice`, `remarks`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 5566,
>   ?, 2020-01-31 03:59:58, 2020-01-31 03:59:58))"

**code in controller is**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Salesprice;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
public function store(Request $request) 
{
         try 
          {
              $user = auth('api')->user();

                 $this->validate($request,[
                    'book_id'=>'required', 
                    'salesprice'=>'required', 
                     ]);
                    $Salesprice= Salesprice::create([
                    'book_id'=>$request['book_id'], 
                    'salesprice'=>$request['salesprice'], 
                    // 'setdate'=>$request['setdate'],  
                    'setby'=> $user->id, 
                    'lastmodifiedby'=>$user->id, 
                    'remarks'=>$request['remarks']
                    ]);
                    return response()->json($Salesprice);

            }

          catch (Exception $e) 
          {
                        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
          }
}
```

**code in migration and model is**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Salesprice extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'book_id','salesprice','setby_id','modifiedby_id','remarks'
    ];
     public function Book()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Book');
    }
     public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
    protected $dates=['deleted_at'];
}


 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('salesprices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
             $table->bigInteger('book_id')->unsigned();
             $table->bigInteger('salesprice');
             $table->bigInteger('setby_id')->unsigned();
             $table->bigInteger('modifiedby_id')->unsigned();
              $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
              $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: try this `Auth::user()` instead of `auth('api')->user()`  and check it works or not

Comment: I did, it dose not work.

Comment: check the store function it is doing the insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth()->user()`is correct 
The only thing you have to do is to change your

setby to setby_id Becaseu you're doing:

```
'setby'=> $user->id,
```

but your column is named setby_id, so you need:

```
'setby_id'=> $user->id,
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this field cannot be nullable.

So when you insert the value without `setby_id`, it will fail.

Change `setby` to `setby_id`

```php
$Salesprice= Salesprice::create([
                    ... 
                    'setby_id'=> $user->id,  // change to setby_id
                    ...
                    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's wrong with `auth()->user()`.

You're doing:

```
'setby'=> $user->id,
```

but your column is named `setby_id`, so you need:

```
'setby_id'=> $user->id,
```

You'll have the same issue with `lastmodifiedby` versus `modifiedby_id`.